# Hook or function to upload media via url

Tags: uploads

I am working on image aggregation site. Is there a wordpress hook or function to upload media especially image if a url is provided to it? Rest I can do with wp_handle_upload function.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`media_handle_sideload`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_sideload) in Codex:

```
$url = "http://s.wordpress.org/style/images/wp3-logo.png";
$tmp = download_url( $url );
$post_id = 1;
$desc = "The WordPress Logo";

// Set variables for storage
// fix file filename for query strings
preg_match('/[^\?]+\.(jpg|JPG|jpe|JPE|jpeg|JPEG|gif|GIF|png|PNG)/', $file, $matches);
$file_array['name'] = basename($matches[0]);
$file_array['tmp_name'] = $tmp;

// If error storing temporarily, unlink
if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) {
    @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
    $file_array['tmp_name'] = '';
}

// do the validation and storage stuff
$id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $post_id, $desc );

// If error storing permanently, unlink
if ( is_wp_error($id) ) {
    @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
    return $id;
}

$src = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );
```

Comment: what does $post_id requires? Will I have to specify post_id value or will it work itself?

Comment: $post_id is the ID of the post you want to attach the file to and is required. if you're not attaching the file to a post, use [`wp_handle_sideload`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_sideload).

Comment: how can I test this code? If using as a function where should I call that function.

Comment: presumably you've got some sort of form submission happening? how are you handling the process of submitting a URL? you could simply put it in a page template for testing purposes.

Comment: What I am doing is getting an image url via curl method and then, upload it to wp content folder from there it will be used to make auto post by wp_insert_post function. One problem is media_handle_sideload requires post_id and wp_insert_post function requires image id for adding it as thumbnail. Which should I do before and then testing it as a whole.

Comment: Is it possible that I can give post id myself?

Comment: you insert the post which gives you back the post id, then add the image which gives you attachment id, then set post thumbnail using post and image ids.

Comment: What does $file variable contains present in this line:
preg_match('/[^\?]+\.(jpg|JPG|jpe|JPE|jpeg|JPEG|gif|GIF|png|PNG)/', $file, $matches);

Comment: Milo, can you tell me what does $file variable contains?? By working of preg_match function, it should be a string but the code in your answer makes $file undefined.

Comment: oh, not sure, I just copied the example straight from the Codex. I assume that's actually supposed to be `$url`.